# How to get output with maximum probability from the all the predicted outputs from dense layer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, data-science

I trained a neural network for sign language recognition. Here's my output layer  `model.add(Dense(units=26,activation="softmax"))`
Now I'm getting probability for all 26 alphabets. Somehow I'm getting 99% accuracy when I test this model `accuracy = model.evaluate(x=test_X,y=test_Y,batch_size=32)`. I'm new at this. I can't understand how this code works and I'm missing something major here. How to get a 1D list having just the predicted alphabet in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get probabilities you need to do something like this:

```
prediction = model.predict(test_X)
probs = prediction.max(1)
```

But it is important to remember that softmax doesn't exactly provide probabilities of each class.

Comment: Is it okay to use this? And how the model gets accuracy on the test dataset then? predicting for all alphabets?

Comment: I think it is okay to use this. As for calculating accuracy, basically it works like this: for each sample the predicted class is the class with the highest probability. You can get it by `prediction.argmax(1)`. Then the predicted class is compared to the original class.

Answer (score 1):

To get outputs with maximum probability in a single list, run:

```
np.argmax(model.predict(x_test),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing alphabet is a list with all alphabet symbols `alphabet = ['a', 'b', ...]`

```
pred = model.predict(test_X)
pred_ind = pred.max(1)
pred_alphabet = [alphabet[ind] for ind in pred_ind]
```

will give you the list with predicted symbols.

Answer (score 0):

In neural networks first layer is for the input image you have. Let's say your image is 32x32 pixels. In that case you would have 32x32x3 nodes in the input layer. This 3 comes for the RGA color scheme. Then depending on your design and model you should use appropriate number of hidden input layers. At most scenarios we use 2 hidden input layers. Then the final layer is for the number of distinct classes you have. Let's say you're going to identify 26 distinct signs. Then you will have 26 nodes in the final layer.

`model.evaluate(x=test_X,y=test_Y,batch_size=32)`
I think here you're trying to make predictions on your test data set. At first you may have separated your data set into train and test sets. Here test_X stands for the images in test set. test_Y stands for corresponding labels. You're trying to evaluate your network by taking 32 images at a time. That's the meaning of batch_size=32.

I think this information might helpful for you to understand what you're doing. But your question is not clear. Please refer the below tutorial. That might helpful for you.
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/10/keras-tutorial-how-to-get-started-with-keras-deep-learning-and-python/